# How to read Chinese Characters from Oracle UTF8 Database using PLSQL Developer

Tags: oracle, encoding, plsql, globalization, plsqldeveloper

I have an Oracle Database with character set AL32UTF8, but I am not able to read some information (ex. Chinese characters). How can I configure my PLSQL Developer to read these characters?

By the way, when I read this information it appears such as ???

I'm using Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

It's necessary to change the NLS_LANG registry in the following route HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_ODACHome2

And set it with the properly language. In my case it was : AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

Anyway...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set NLS_LANG Environment Variable also works for me.

Variable: NLS_LANG

Value: AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

Answer (score -1):

Your `NLS_CHARACTERSET` should be set to AL32UTF8 and also make sure that parameter `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is set to UTF8.

```
 SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = 'UTF8';
```

Comment: It can't be change from the sessionhttps://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=999599

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=999599    Other solution???? Indeed the character set for the database is already AL32UTF8